# is there a reddit/linear style open source markdown text editor for react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, markdown, editor

Is there a react component/library which would allow me to implement a text editor that uploads in markdown, but also allows me to paste images as base64 pngs, and render that data when I want?

[image]

react-md-editor has its split-pane editing but I'm looking for something more notion-esque. It's a tall order but is there something that I can use? I want something I can edit and see the formatting in real-time, but I need to upload said data in mark-down. Notion/Linear/Reddit seem to have the functionality I'm looking for.

I've searched for the last 1-1.5 hours but haven't been able to find something usable :(